# Is there any way to use pd.sum while keeping (!) duplicates?

Tags: python, pandas, sum, duplicates

Suppose I have a dataframe DS_df with columns year, dealamount, CCS, LAultimateborrowerparentcountry among others. For every specific year, I'm seeking the sum for each LAultimateparentcountry:

```
    year    dealamount  CCS                 LAultimateparentcountry

0   2013    37522700.0  Albania_Azerbaijan  Albania
1   2013    37522700.0  Albania_Azerbaijan  Albania
2   2016    436341300.0 Albania_Greece      Albania
3   2019    763189200.0 Albania_Russia      Albania
4   2019    943518742.0 Albania_USA         Albania
```

```
total2019 =DS_df[DS_df["year"]==2020].groupby("LAultimateparentcountry")["dealamount"].sum().sort_index()
```

This for example works well and gives me the total sum for 2019, but only the unique value in a series:

`Albania 1,706,707,942`

What I need, is  a panda series w/ the same length as the corresponding year (This means that every country pair (CCS) should only be reflected once, but the individual country (LAultimateparentcountry) should appear as often as the pair does) That is, for the case above the output for 2019 would need to look like this: (Two country pairs, thus we need to include the sum twice in the newly created series. )

```
Albania 1,706,707,942
Albania 1,706,707,942
```

Appreciate any help. Really lost on that one.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want this?

```
df = df.convert_dtypes()
df['dealamount'] = df.groupby('year')['dealamount'].transform(sum)
```

**Output -**

```
   year  dealamount                 CCS LAultimateparentcountry
0  2013    75045400  Albania_Azerbaijan                 Albania
1  2013    75045400  Albania_Azerbaijan                 Albania
2  2016   436341300      Albania_Greece                 Albania
3  2019  1706707942      Albania_Russia                 Albania
4  2019  1706707942         Albania_USA                 Albania
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DS_df = DS_df.drop_duplicates()
DS_df["Total"] = DS_df.groupby(["LAultimateparentcountry", "year"])["dealamount"] \
                      .transform(sum)
```

```
>>> DS_df
   year   dealamount                 CCS LAultimateparentcountry         Total
0  2013   37522700.0  Albania_Azerbaijan                 Albania  3.752270e+07
2  2016  436341300.0      Albania_Greece                 Albania  4.363413e+08
3  2019  763189200.0      Albania_Russia                 Albania  1.706708e+09
4  2019  943518742.0         Albania_USA                 Albania  1.706708e+09
```

Comment: How would I now go about storing the results into different variables? I.e., I want for each year separate variables ````total2019 =DS_df[DS_df["year"]==2020].groupby("LAultimateparentcountry")["dealamount"].sum().sort_index()```` drops the duplicates and sums the countries all into one.

Comment: `total2013, total2016, total2019 = DS_df.drop_duplicates(["year", "LAultimateparentcountry"])["Total"].tolist()`but it's hard coded. It doesn't work if there is another year.